# Emberjs - How to wait until a template is fully rendered before accessing its children

Tags: ember.js

Is there a way to wait until a template is fully rendered before accessing its children through a view, using jquery for instance?

didInsertElement doesn't seem to work as expected for me. I need to add an additional half second delay before the template is fully constructed. The template iterates over an array in the controller and creates several divs. it's these divs that aren't accessible immediately, even when I override didInsertElement.

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle please ? I think didInsertElement should be definitively the way of doing this. Perhaps you have to use a collection view, or at least using a {{view}} helper inside the loop.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not aware of how you insert those childViews, but one way to do it, is as follows:

```
didInsertElement: function(){
  if (this.$().find(".myAwesomeChildViews").length > 0) {  // <-- adapt this to your needs
     // my childViews are inserted
  } else {
     Ember.run.next(this, function() {
        this.didInsertElement();
     });
  }
}
```

The important thing here is that didInsertElement() will keep being called until the check evaluates to true.

---

Even better, you can refactor it as follows:

```
Ember.View.reopen({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        this._super();
        this.setIsRendered();
    },

     setIsRendered: function() {
        if (!!this.$()) {
            this.set('isRendered', true);
        } else {
            Ember.run.next(this, function() {
                this.setIsRendered();
            });
        }
    },
});
```

And then in your view:

```
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
   areMyChildViewsRendered: function() {
      return this.get('childViews').everyProperty('isRendered');
   }.property('chilViews.@each.isRendered')
});
```

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks Zack! Just tried to vote you up but my rep ain't up to it :|

Answer (score 16):

I recently added something to Ember that will do this more elegantly: an `afterRender` queue. See [this commit](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/512327c0128f53d4a0d6828ab38f27c6ccf686ec), in particular the test for an example of usage.